How to skip first element of each row in csv file without changing csv file
I am using a for loop in python to convert the values from the csv file into integer and float then putting them in a list in the code itself but the problem is with that the csv file doesn't only have numbers but also word before each data row
eg. years 1998.....
I have tried to pop it but it doesn't work as the for loop doesn't function as intended because of what I stated earlier and I cant change the csv file and I have no other idea on how to properly fix it
with open("C:/Users/yuhon/Downloads/sgexports_dataset.csv") as openfile: 
    csvreader = csv.reader(openfile) 
    next(csvreader) 
    years = [] 
    americaExports = [] 
    asiaExports = [] 
    europeExports = []
    oceaniaExports = [] 
    africaExports = []
    euExports = [] 
    for row in csvreader: 
        years.append(int(row[0])) 
        americaExports.append(float(row[1]))
        asiaExports.append(float(row[2]))
        europeExports.append(float(row[3]))
        oceaniaExports.append(float(row[4]))
        africaExports.append(float(row[5]))
        euExports.append(float(row[6]))

this is the csv file
Area,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009
America,30407.5,31517.7,33185.2,26015.3,26942.1,28082.6,29964.2,30481.6,35900.7,39597.6,38459.6,32154.4
Asia,50197.3,56987.4,73466.9,66382,67224.1,89338.3,107412.6,127210.4,137654.4,140908.6,149612.6,122946.2
Europe,21386.8,22748.6,22519.8,19921.3,18503.2,24347.6,30307,32611.5,34668,34695.2,33286.6,26648.6
Oceania,2938.3,3979,5001.8,4859.3,5323.4,7024.5,10203.1,14154.8,15486.2,15555,18965.2,13468
Africa,987.7,1092.3,1764.4,1266.5,1444.7,1764.9,2313.5,2989.4,3668.6,4146.7,7293.9,4786
European Union,20875.6,22289.8,21868.6,19233.2,17916.9,23591.8,29273.1,31543.5,32923.4,33233.6,31713.5,24840.8

as you can see in the data above at the start of each row there is a word and I am not sure of how to skip the first element of each row as the list is supposed to have only integers and I cannot change the csv file and the rest of my code would not work if I do not use integers and float lists

Index 0 appears to be a string, consistently - and therefore cannot (in these cases) and should not be converted to an int.  It just appears that your indexing is off.

@s3dev how would you change the indexing so that the string would not be converted to an int

Looks like you're confusing rows with columns...

in this project the aim is to create a program that will initialise lists with full data from the csv file and to create a menu program with options

Display exports to Europe during 1998 to 2009.
Of the user’s selected area, display
a) the average export value in millions in the 7-year span of 2000
to 2006.
b) the lowest export value in that period and the year in which it
occurred.
Display the years and the export values if the export values have changed by at least 5%
over the previous year of the users selected area



Make plots of exports
a)to america and EU against year as line plots
b)to asia against year as barchart


Instead of using row[0] to row[6], use row[1] to row[7].  What is the difficulty?

@JohnGordon I think the problem is that in the csv file its listed as area then the values and I do not know how to code it such that it would assign the list to each row instead of going through just the first list if that makes sense

You can't really process that file in the way you're approaching it. It's not entirely clear what data structure you're trying to end up with, but I'd suggest something like:
exports = {
    'America': {1998: 30407.5, 1999: 31517.7, ...},
    'Asia': {1998: 50197.3, ...},
    ...
}

To get from your CSV file to that data structure, this'd be the code:
exports = {}

with open(".../sgexports_dataset.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
    years = list(map(int, headers[1:]))  # [1998, 1999, ...]

    for row in reader:
        exports[row[0]] = dict(zip(years, map(float, row[1:])))


Your approach was wrong because treated columns and rows the wrong way around. Each row is one area, not each column.

The basic problem is that your code expects the csv file to be organized in a different way than it actually is.
Your code expects each csv row to have the year as the first column, then the America exports for that year as the second column, then the Asia exports for that year as the third column, etc etc.
But the csv file is not organized that way.
